# Proof of $\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^n(x)\cos(nx)dx=\frac{\pi}{2^n}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am trying to prove the following:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^n(x)\cos(nx)dx=\frac{\pi}{2^n}$$

so far I have got:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^n(x)\cos(nx)dx=\Re\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^n(x)\left(\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)\right)dx\right)=\Re\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^n(x)e^{inx}dx\right)$$
since $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ through Euler's formula and then $(e^{ix})^n=\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)$ from De Moivre's theorem.

We also know that:
$$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2} \therefore \cos^n(x)=\frac{(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^n}{2^n}$$
$$\therefore I=\frac{1}{2^n}\Re\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{inx}\left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)^ndx\right)=\frac{1}{2^n}\Re\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{inx}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\left(\begin{matrix}n\\r\end{matrix}\right)(e^{ix})^{n-r}(e^{-ix})^rdx\right)=\frac{1}{2^n}\Re\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n}\left(\begin{matrix}n\\r\end{matrix}\right)\int_{0}^{\pi}(e^{ix})^{2n-2r}dx\right)=\frac{1}{2^n}\Re\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n}\left(\begin{matrix}n\\r\end{matrix}\right)\left[\frac{e^{(2n-2r)ix}}{(2n-2r)i}\right]_{0}^{\pi}\right)$$

I have found the same problem but a confusing layout, shown below. Could someone show me where to go from here?

https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-integrate-cos-n-x-cos-nx-taking-limits-as-0-to-%CF%80 (1)

EDIT:
$$I=\frac{1}{2^n}\Re\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n}\left(\begin{matrix}n\\r\end{matrix}\right)\left[\frac{e^{(n-r)2i\pi}-1}{2(n-r)i}\right]\right)$$

for when $r=n$ we effectively get $$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{e^{2xi\pi}}{2xi}\right)=\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{2i\pi\,e^{2xi\pi}}{2i}\right)=\pi$$

FURTHER EDIT:
since all other elements in the summation will be imaginary then the summation will evaluate to $\pi$ therefore I have proved it

Comment: One comment: in the last expression, you should really separate the sum into $\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}[\text{something}]$ and the part coming from $r=n$.  Then, you will probably see where $\pi$ comes from.

Comment: I think nothing is wrong, you should be a little bit careful (what if $r=n$?). I think you are REALLY close to the solution. I'm sure you can write the last word to finish it!

Comment: so when i get $r=n$ i get $\frac{e^0}{0i}$ don't I?

Comment: In the quora's link you attached in your question, the answer by John Gilmore is not entirely correct, by the way.  He should have gotten $B=0$, that is, $$\int_0^\pi\,\cos^n(x)\,\sin(nx)\,\text{d}x=0\,.$$

Comment: yeah I felt a lot of what was written didn't seem fully justified so I wasn't sure if it was correct

Comment: $e^{2\pi ki} = 1$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, $n-1$ of your summands are equal to zero. The only non-zero summand is at $r = n$ and in that case you can just evaluate the corresponding integral to be $$\int_0^{\pi}1dx = \pi$$

Comment: is my latest edit with the evaluation of the limit correct as to what you have said?

Comment: @HenryLee you can certainly do it like that but that seems a bit of an overkill. Plus, L'hopital's rule as far as i know is limited to real functions.

Comment: ah right, I am new to evaluating limits so didn't know this thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @dezdichado LHR is not limited to real-valued functions.

Answer (score 4):

Although I recognize that this post is relatively old, let me propose another strategy to solving this problem.

Let

$$ I(n) = \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{n}(x)\cdot\cos(n\cdot x)\,\text{d}x\text{,}$$

where $n\in\mathbb{N}^{0}$.

Perform integration by parts,

$$ \int u\,\text{d}v=u\cdot v-\int v\,\text{d}u\text{,} $$

where

$$ u = \cos^{n}(x)\Leftrightarrow\text{d}u = -n\cdot\cos^{n-1}(x)\cdot \sin(x)\,\text{d}x\text{,} \\
    \text{d}v = \cos(n\cdot x)\,\text{d}x\Leftrightarrow v = 1/n\cdot\sin(n\cdot x)\text{.} $$

Then,

$$ \begin{align} 
I(n) & = \left.1/n\cdot\cos^{n}(x)\cdot\sin(n\cdot x)\right|_0^{\pi}+\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{n-1}(x)\cdot\sin(n\cdot x)\cdot\sin(x)\,\text{d}x \\
  & = \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{n-1}(x)\cdot\sin(n\cdot x)\cdot\sin(x)\,\text{d}x\text{.}
   \end{align} $$

Take the sum of both integral forms:

$$ \begin{align} 
2\cdot I(n) & = \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{n}(x)\cdot\cos(n\cdot x)\,\text{d}x+\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{n-1}(x)\cdot\sin(n\cdot x)\cdot\sin(x)\,\text{d}x \\
  & = \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{n-1}(x)\cdot\left(\cos(n\cdot x)\cdot\cos(x)+\sin(n\cdot x)\cdot\sin(x)\right)\text{d}x\text{.}
   \end{align} $$

Make use of the angle-difference identity for the cosine function,

$$ \cos(\alpha-\beta) = \cos(\alpha)\cdot\cos(\beta)+\sin(\alpha)\cdot\sin(\beta)\text{.} $$

Then,

$$ 2\cdot I(n) = \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{n-1}(x)\cdot\cos\left((n-1)\cdot x\right)\,\text{d}x\text{.} $$

Recognize that

$$ 2\cdot I(n) = I(n-1) $$

Then,

$$ \begin{align}
2\cdot I(n-1) & = I(n-2) \\
2\cdot I(n-2) & = I(n-3) \\
       & \;\;\vdots \\
2\cdot I(1)   & = I(0)\text{.}
   \end{align} $$

It follows that

$$ 2^{n}\cdot I(n) = I(0)\Rightarrow I(n) = \frac{I(0)}{2^{n}}\text{.} $$

According to the integral form,

$$ I(0) = \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{0}(x)\cdot\cos(0\cdot x)\,\text{d}x = \int_{0}^{\pi}\text{d}x = \pi\text{.} $$

Thus,

$$ I(n) = \frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\text{,} $$

where $n\in\mathbb{N}^{0}$.

Comment: Wow nice. I really appreciate that you have managed to do this without use of complex analysis and just using simple methods like IBP (+1)

Comment: @HenryLee That's a general strategy I like to use: First trying to figure out whether a problem can be solved by means of more "general" methods, and later more intricate methods.

Comment: You could probably also evaluate the $\cos^{n}(x)\cdot\sin(n\cdot x)$ congener by labeling the integrals $I$ and $J$ and establishing the relation $I + i\cdot J$. But that's a problem for another time ;)

Answer (score 3):

You may just exploit the binomial theorem. By the parity of $\cos$ we have
$$ F(n) = \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^n(x)\cos(nx)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^n(x)\cos(nx)\,dx $$
and $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{nix}e^{-mix}\,dx = 2\pi\delta(m,n)$, so
$$ F(n) = \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^n (e^{nix}+e^{-nix})\,dx=\frac{2\cdot 2\pi}{2^{n+2}}=\frac{\pi}{2^n} $$
since $(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}e^{(n-2k)ix}$ and the only terms that matters are the ones associated to $k=0$ and $k=n$.